# cant consume queue from topic exchange rabbitmq

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq

I have a weird issue with rabbit mq,my publisher service sends message to queue and i can see it there,in my consumer i cant get it even thought i go there with router key and exact queue name

```
  var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "myhst",
                                       UserName = "payoutservice", 
                                                   Password = pass};
        using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
        using ( _channel = connection.CreateModel())
        {
            _channel.ExchangeDeclare("payin-exchange", ExchangeType.Topic);

            _channel.QueueDeclare("OpenPaymentReceiveResponseQueue", durable: true, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);


            _channel.QueueBind(queue: "OpenPaymentReceiveResponseQueue",
                              exchange: "payin-exchange",
                              routingKey: "payin");
            //}

            Console.WriteLine(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(_channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body.ToArray();
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
                var routingKey = ea.RoutingKey;

            };
```

in the last part doesn't go inside consumer.Received and does not even hit my breakpoint inside there

Answer (score 1):

Have you included an explicit call to for the consumer to consume from the queue?  E.g.,

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: queueName,
                             autoAck: true,
                             consumer: consumer);
```

There are helpful examples that you can look over here:  https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-dotnet.html